# MyLocationOverlay changing the update time

Tags: java, android, gps, location

As you know. Calling `enableMyLocation` function calls the `GPS` service very frequently and wasting the `battery` life very fast, how can I edit the time of getting updates? So it will call the `GPS` every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: please post some code of what u did